# How to calculate an ellipse area in pixel?

Tags: r, image, image-processing, geometry, ellipse

First,I converted the rgb image into hsv

```
  res = RGB_to_HSV(img)
```

Then, I used locator (4) to define four (x,y) coordinate

```
  x<-c(0.3546019, 0.7089434, 0.5494897, 0.5534268)
  y<-c(0.5302427, 0.5158414, 0.5907282, 0.4351941)
  dat<-as.matrix(cbind(x,y))
```

Here's some information related to the centre and

'ellipsoid' in 2 dimensions:

```
center = ( 0.53250 0.51396 ); squared ave.radius d^2 =  2 

and shape matrix =

        x           y
   x  0.01592764 -0.00089633

   y -0.00089633  0.00310081

   hence, area  =  0.043796 

  They gives the minimal volume area

 the major axis= 0.19

 the minor axis = 0.07
```

I have tried the following:

```
 result <- as.data.frame(dat) %>%
 summarise(pixels = n())
  result
```

but this gives the number of pixel of x and y coordinates

Any clue how to calculate the area in pixel?

Comment: How are those coordinates defined? What units are those?

Comment: @CrisLuengo I said I used the function locator()

Comment: A simple estimator: 0.043796 (area) divided by pixel area?

Comment: @Friede what do you mean by the pixel area coz that’s what I am trying find.

Comment: Please make your q reproducible, it is easier to help and demonastrate ideas then: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Read the docs, and figure out what coordinate system `locator()` uses. I don't know R, but if you know what that coordinate system is, then I can help you figure out the size in pixels.

Comment: @CrisLuengo the coordinate system (0,0) and the max value is 1.

Comment: IF you are using a unit coordinate system that gives an area of 0.043796 then the area in pixels is the total number of display pixels times that value. The resolution of the image (inner black excluding outer white pixels) is 510 by 349, thus the area is 0.043796 * 510 * 349. HOWEVER! the unit coordinates and the image suggest that the pixels are square, meaning that the image may not represent the whole unit area 1 by 1. You need to know the area of one pixel, which is information you have not provided nor have you provided any means of determining that value

Comment: @Blindman67how can I identify the area of one pixel?

Comment: For getting an ellipse through 4 points use [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4471344). For many formulas (included the area) use [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#General_ellipse). The rest is how to compare units to pixels, a matter of scaling